# Would a woman have to cover an artificial limb for tznius purposes?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, parts-of-the-body, handicap-disabled-impair

If a woman has an artificial limb like a leg or arm, would they need to cover that the same way they cover the rest of their body for tznius purposes?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16669/prosthetic-limbs-in-halacha

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35963/759

Comment: Does the artificial limb look realistic? If so, how is it different then a picture?